# Using COUNT value from sub-SELECT query to determine FETCH ROW limit

Tags: sql, db2, fetch, with-statement

I'm curious to see if there's any way to rewrite the following invalid DB2 Query to get what I need:

```
WITH pull AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM email_list
), 
pull_count AS (
    SELECT count(email) as email_count
    FROM email_list
)

SELECT *
FROM pull
FETCH FIRST integer(email_count / 2) ROWS ONLY
```

I'm getting the 'Token INTEGER was not valid. Valid tokens: ROW ROWS' error.

My goal is to use the 2nd WITH statement, pull_count, to set the FETCH limit for the 1st WITH statement, pull.  I'm only looking to SELECT for half of the rows available.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FETCH FIRST clause can't use an expression, as you've found. It accepts a non-negative integer only.

There is not a pretty way to do this, but it's possible by using OLAP functions.  These may not be present on your version of DB2 (if you're on DB2 for Linux/UNIX/Windows then they are probably there).

Assuming your table has columns email and name:

```
with pull as (
   select 
      email, 
      name, 
      rownumber() over(order by email) as row, 
      count(email) over () as cnt
   from 
      email_list
)
select 
   email,
   name 
from 
   pull
where
   row <= cnt/2;
```

This may not perform very well;  and in fact it may be more efficient to simply execute 2 queries -- 1 doing the count, and the other fetching the specific number of rows you care about.

Comment: This works but you're absolutely right about splitting it up into two queries.  Thanks!